# taken a picture and upload it to facebook wall gets me an error

Tags: android, android-camera

this is my code for taking a picture from my android app and upload it to facebook wall.

```
photo_up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.camera_foto_button);
photo_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);              
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
    }
  });


switch(requestCode){
        case CAMERA_REQUEST:{
          Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
          bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);         
          byteArray = stream.toByteArray(); // convert camera photo to byte array  
          Bundle params = new Bundle();       
          params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);      
          params.putString("message", "Have fun");       
          Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params,"POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
        break;
```

When the picture is taken I get after 2 secs a force close. This is the log:

```
05-17 18:04:47.756: E/AndroidRuntime(272): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
05-17 18:04:47.756: E/AndroidRuntime(272): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 18:04:47.756: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.myco.android.myapp.Gallery1$PhotoUploadListener.onComplete(Gallery1.java:368)
05-17 18:04:47.756: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:254)
E/dalvikvm(272): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Moreover image is not saved in SD card, which I also want.
All the required permissions have been added in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works for me

```
private void uploadImage() {

        if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            byte[] data = null;

            Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(final_image_bitmap);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
            params.putByteArray("picture", data);

            AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
            mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST",
                    new SampleUploadListener(), null);

        } else {
            Log.v("Session is not valid.", "");
        }
```

Comment: what is the final_image_bitmap in .decodeFile?? result from my camera?

Comment: your image file's path (for example String final_image_bitmap="/sdcard/sample/mImage.png")

Comment: yes but with the above code, image is not saved on the sd. can you edit the code and please give me the code that saves it in the sd cause everything I tried does not seem to work. Thanks!